# Cannot get variables to interpolate in underscore.js template while jasmine.js testing

Tags: backbone.js, underscore.js, jasmine

EDIT: Forgot to remind the reader that I remembered to set templateSettings as follows:

```
_.templateSettings = {
    interpolate : /\{\{([\s\S]+?)\}\}/g
};
```

I'm having a hard time getting a varialbe to interpolate in underscore, while running my Jasmine specs.  Given the template, rendering method, and jasmine test below, I am able to get the template to interpolate variables properly via:

```
_.template(
  boneHeaderInstance.template.html(), 
  { id:boneHeaderInstance.id,  
    columns:boneHeaderInstance.columns
  }
)
```

While this fails to interpolate the columns variable:

```
boneHeader = Backbone.View.extend({
  el: $('#boneTableHeader'),
  template: $('#boneTableHeaderTemplate'),
  initialize: function(){
    this.id = 'boneTableHeader';
    this.el = $( '#' + this.id );
    this.columns = 'blah';
    this.template = $( '#' + this.id + 'Template' );
    this.render();
    return this;
  },
  render: function(){
    var that = this;
    var data = {id: that.id, columns: that.columns}
    this.el.html( _.template( this.template.html(), data ) );
  }
});
```

Template:

```
<script type = 'text/template' id = 'boneTableHeaderTemplate'>
  <tr id = "{{obj.id}}Row">
    {{obj.columns}}
  </tr>
</script>
```

In Render Method:

```
render: function(){
  var that = this;
  var data = {id: that.id, columns: that.columns}
  this.el.html( _.template( that.template.html(), data ) );
}
```

Jasmine Test:

```
describe('boneHeader', function(){
  beforeEach(function(){
    boneHeaderInstance = boneTableInstance.header;
  }); 
  describe('rendering', function(){
    it('should have expected html', function(){
      expect( 
        boneHeaderInstance.el.html().replace(/\s\t\n/ , '', 'g') 
      ).toEqual( 
        _.template(boneHeaderInstance.template.html(), 
        { id:boneHeaderInstance.id,  
          columns:boneHeaderInstance.columns
        }).replace(/\s\t\n/ , '', 'g') 
      );
    }); 
  }); 
});
```

Jasmine Result:

```
Expected ' <tr id="boneTableHeaderRow"></tr> ' to equal ' <tr id = "boneTableHeaderRow"> blah </tr> '
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have various problems. First of all, [Underscore uses `<% %>` for templates](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/#template) unless you change it with something like:

```
_.templateSettings = {
  interpolate : /\{\{(.+?)\}\}/g
};
```

So your template should look like this:

```
<script type = 'text/template' id = 'boneTableHeaderTemplate'>
    <tr id = "<%= obj.id %>Row">
        <td><%= obj.columns %></td>
    </tr>
</script>
```

I've also fixed the HTML error you had in your template, you can't have a text node as an immediate child of a `<tr>` and there's no telling what sort of chicanery a browser will get up to if you try such a thing.

Secondly, `_.template()` is usually used to return a compiled version of a template and that compiled version is a function that you execute to get the final HTML:

```
var t    = _.template(some_template_html);
var html = t(data);
```

So you probably want something like this in your constructor:

```
this.template = _.template($('#' + this.id + 'Template').html());
```

and this in your `render`:

```
this.el.html(this.template(data));
```

You can do it all at once with `_.template(template_html, context)` though.

Thirdly, you're referencing `obj.id` and `obj.columns` in your template but you're only giving it `id` and `columns` so either drop the `obj.` prefixes from your template or alter `data` thusly:

```
var data = {
    obj: {
        id: that.id,
        columns: that.columns
    }
};
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/NYLqH/

You'll have to fix your test to account for the corrected HTML of course.

Comment: Thanks.  I thought I had included the `templateSettings`.  I'm using that and will update my question to reflect this.  Sorry for the confusion.  Looking over the rest of the answer now.

Comment: I'm still digesting the rest of the answer.  I agree that `obj` should not be needed.  Do you know why `obj.id` and `obj.columns` works in this code `_.template(
  boneHeaderInstance.template.html(), 
  { id:boneHeaderInstance.id,  
    columns:boneHeaderInstance.columns
  }
)` with the template provided in my answer?  If not, no biggie, just wondering.  Also, I don't think that is an issue.  Considering it interpolates correctly for `obj.id` per the Jasmine message: `Expected ' <tr id="boneTableHeaderRow"></tr> ' to equal ' <tr id = "boneTableHeaderRow"> blah </tr> '`

Comment: Which means your probably correct that placing the `{{obj.columns}}` directly after the `<tr>` is probably the issue.  Thanks!

Comment: @kikuchiyo: You can compile and execute the template in one go with `_.template(html, data)`. I don't see how `{{obj.id}}` would work without an `obj` in the data though.

Comment: Indeed, the silly example I was providing, without a `<td>` tag within the `<tr>` tag was causing this.  Damn, that was dumb of me.  +1 for pointing this out somewhere in the middle of your answer.

Comment: @kikuchiyo: Cool, as long as you have it fixed. Bad HTML causes all sorts of irritating problems :)

Comment: Yes, I'm using the equivalent of `_.template(html, data)` as in my original answer.  Everything is the same except for my poorly thought out example.  I know.  I recall reading that using `obj` works somewhere online and I just included it.  Read that it was the default name for the object passed through template.  Best not to use it though if I don't have to.  Thanks again for lending some fresh eyes to my code :)